# How to send an email to more than one recepient using Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail

Tags: perl, email

I am trying to write a simple perl script for sending emails using Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail.

Following is the script that I have written so far.

```
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail;

   my $mail=Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail->new( -smtp=>'smtp.gmail.com',
                                       -login=>'abc@gmail.com',
                                       -pass=>'12345',
                   -port=>587,
                   -verbose=>1,
                   -debug=>1);

   $mail->send(-to=>'pqr@gmail.com', -subject=>'Hello!',     -body=>'Just testing it', -verbose=>1, -debug=>1);

   $mail->bye;
```

This script works fine. 
How can I send this email to more than one person( i.e. more than one email id in the "to" field).
I have tried using:

```
$mail->send(-to=>['pqr@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com'], -subject=>'Hello!',     -body=>'Just testing it', -verbose=>1, -debug=>1);
```

But I get an error:

```
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x23b77a8)>>> RCPT TO:<ARRAY(0x1ee5e78)>
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x23b77a8)<<< 553 5.1.2 The address specified is not a  valid RFC-5321 address. w78sm722980qka.25 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~peco/Email-Send-SMTP-Gmail-0.1.1/lib/Email/Send/SMTP/Gmail.pm): put commas between the email addresses.

> send(-to=>'', [-subject=>'', -cc=>'', -bcc=>'', -replyto=>'', -body=>'', -attachments=>''])
>   It composes and sends the email in one shot
>
> to, cc, bcc: **comma separated email addresses**
>   attachments: comma separated files with full path

```
$mail->send(-to=>'a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com,...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add all recipients as a comma separated list:

```
(-to=>'pqr@gmail.com,rec2@gmail.com' ...
```